# ORACLE SQL - display count and 0

Tags: sql, oracle, count, null

I have a simple code displaying the countrynames and the amount of citys with a population between 100000 and 200000 in it. Now i am trying to display the countrynames where are no citys with this populationrange as well. The count for this citys should be displayed as 0 in the table.

```
  SELECT country.name, COUNT(City.population) 
    FROM (city JOIN country ON  city.country = country.code)
     WHERE city.population BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
      GROUP BY country.name
      ORDER BY country.name;
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` to also include countries without any cities with that population:

```
SELECT country.name, COUNT(City.population) 
FROM country
LEFT JOIN city
    ON  city.country = country.code
    AND city.population BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
GROUP BY country.name
ORDER BY country.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with union

```
  SELECT country.name, COUNT(City.population) 
  FROM (city JOIN country ON  city.country = country.code)
  WHERE city.population BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
  GROUP BY country.name
  UNION
  SELECT country.name, COUNT(City.population) 
  FROM (city JOIN country ON  city.country = country.code)
  WHERE city.population < 100000 OR city.population >200000
  GROUP BY country.name
  ORDER BY country.name;
```

I can't test it in this moment.

Comment: I assume you mean OR in the instead of AND in the second select. Anyway, the query will return same country twice if it has cities both within and outside the range. (At least when different numbers of them.)

Answer (score 0):

try this! using case is the easiest way from my point of view. sorry but can't test it myself

```
SELECT country.name, count(case when city.population BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 then city.population else 0 end) 
FROM (city JOIN country ON  city.country = country.code)
  GROUP BY country.name
  ORDER BY country.name;
```

Comment: You have a GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions

Comment: Countries without any cities at all will be missed.

Comment: true/ changed it.

Comment: OP wants the number of cities, not the sum of their populations.